# JAXB retrieve inner element with namespace (returns blank)

Tags: java, xml-parsing, jaxb, rss

**I want to unmarshal**

```xml
<item>
    <a10:author>
        <a10:name>AuthorName</a10:name>
    </a10:author>
</item>
```

to

```kotlin
data class Item(val author:String)
```

if possible, by reading `author/name` into `author` field directly.
**If not possible in clean/simple way**, i want to create `Author` class with `name` field, as below. **In below code, `author.name` is empty, but it should not be. Why is it empty?**

Sample XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rss xmlns:a10="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0">
    <channel xmlns:os="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
        <title>SomeTitle</title>
        <link>https://google.com</link>
        <description>SomeDescription</description>
        <os:totalResults>49</os:totalResults>
        <item>
            <link>https://google.com</link>
            <a10:author>
                <a10:name>AuthorName</a10:name>
            </a10:author>
            <title>SomeTitle</title>
            <description>SomeDesc</description>
            <pubDate>Fri, 06 Nov 2020 07:59:27 Z</pubDate>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

All model classes:

```kotlin
@XmlRootElement(name = "rss", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
data class Rss(val channel: RssChannel?) {

    constructor() : this(channel = null)
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "channel", namespace = "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
data class RssChannel  (val link: String,
                        val title: String,
                        val description: String,
                        @field:XmlElement(namespace = "http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/")
                        val totalResults: Int,
                        @field:XmlElement(name = "item")
                        val items: List<Item>?) {

    constructor() : this(link = "", title = "", description = "", totalResults = 0, items = null)
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
data class Item( val title: String,
                 val description: String,
                 val link: String,
                 @field:XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
                 val author: Author,
                 val pubDate: String) {

    constructor() : this(title = "", description = "", link = "", author = Author(), pubDate = "")
}

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
data class Author(@XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
                  val name: String) {

    constructor() : this(name = "")
}
```

Comment: your sample XML has elements without prefix, but there is no namespace for empty prefix.

Comment: yes, and it is valid

Comment: So there is no namespace in rss element, but namespace is specified for Rss class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1) Error was `@field:XmlElement` instead of `@XmlElement`**

This is kotlin property/field distinction error.

From

```kotlin
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
data class Author(@XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
                  val name: String)
```

To

```kotlin
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
data class Author(@field:XmlElement(namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
                  val name: String)
```

**2) Another solution using `@XmlAnyElement`** (extra complexity)

```kotlin
data class Author(@field:XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
                  val elements: MutableList<JAXBElement<String>>)
...

@XmlRegistry
class NameStringFactory {
    @XmlElementDecl(name = "name", namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom")
    fun createName(name: String): JAXBElement<String> {
        return JAXBElement<String>(QName("name"), String::class.java, name)
    }
}

...

val jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(NameStringFactory::class.java,...)
```

---

But i still don't know if removing `Author` class and using `data class Item(val author:String)` instead is possible